# Does anyone have any idea what John from Cincinatti was supposed to be about?

Tags: john-from-cincinnati

I don't know how many of us caught this show in its brief run on HBO, but it was tres bizarre. Levitation, (apparent) teleportation, telepathy...clearly something supernatural was supposed to be going on. But, it was cancelled after the first season.

Does anyone know of any secondary sources that explained what John was supposed to be, and what was going on?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How did the father levitate?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117705/how-did-the-father-levitate)

Comment: @Valorum I know nothing about this show, but the proposed dupe target is both newer and more specific than this one. Surely the duplication should be the other way round, if anything?

Comment: @Randal'Thor - I felt that my answer was more revealing about the character's motivation and the writer's inspiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the executive producer Mark Tinker, "John could be anybody at this point, One of the things that John brings to the show is love, and a forgiveness for anyone and anything that opens people's hearts."

> "John could be anybody at this point, One of the things that John brings to the show is love, and a forgiveness for anyone and anything that opens people's hearts."

And in a NY Post interview, Milch said this about John,

> "He was a variable creature of enormous energy and power, and very little understanding. And that, to me, is kind of what the world is like." [5]

Nichols reiterated the religious connection in an interview with LAist.com:

> "I just heard David Milch say, the show is like what would happen if God wanted to talk to us with relative urgency."

So I don't think they fleshed the whole thing out before the show was cancelled.

This wikia has a lot of info about the show and also a save JFC campaign :)

http://jfc.wikia.com/John_Monad