# How did the father levitate?

Tags: john-from-cincinnati

In the single season series on HBO, John from Cincinnati, the father is seen levitating after a surf session. Does that get explained ever, anywhere?

Comment: I felt that my answer to this one was pretty convincing, within the constraints of the available info and the fact that the writer was being intentionally vague, even with the show's actors and crew. Is there anything else you'd like me to add before considering an acceptance?

Answer (score 1):

### Err. We dunno, and critically, *neither do the people who made the show*.

The show was allegedly heading toward some explanation of these mysterious abilities but the reality is that like other shows that fit into the ['Kudzu Plot'](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/KudzuPlot) trope category, these odd occurrences were most likely included to spawn controversy and provoke audience discussion rather than actually being ***resolvable plot points***.

Notably, even the actor who played the titular John (Bruce Greenwood) is just as baffled [why his character has these abilities](http://www.buddytv.com/articles/john-from-cincinnati/bruce-greenwood-on-his-charact-8588.aspx) as you are.

> “You have to make up theories in your mind, but chances are my guesses
>   are not going to [match] what [John From Cincinnati creator] David
>   Milch comes up with,” Greenwood told TV Guide.
>
> **He also said that asking about how Mitch is able to levitate is not
>   the type of question Milch would respond to with a straight answer.**
>
> **“He would say something like, ‘Because gravity ceases to work against
>   you,’” Bruce Greenwood explained.  “It would become some sort of
>   Socratic afternoon.  I know that there are forces at work that we
>   don't understand, and they will be revealed.**
>
> However, the 50-year-old actor did let on that although his character
>   may feel that his skill is coming from John Monad, that way of
>   thinking is only “a small take on its origin.”
>
> “It’s bigger than John,” Greenwood said.

The show's writer (David Milch) blamed the fact that he was forced to write the scripts in under four months as being responsible for the [lack of coherent worldbuilding](http://www.theguardian.com/tv-and-radio/2012/feb/11/david-milch-luck):

> "Any show is a contract between the audience and the writer and it
>   goes both ways," says Milch. "John From Cincinnati was on air too
>   quickly. I wrote it in four months and that wasn't adequately
>   respectful to the process. The audience has to show a level of faith
>   in the writer, but **it's also the case that the writer cannot justify
>   mystifying the audience."**

Comment: I wanted this show to work so bad because my real name is John and I was living in Cincinnati at the time. I was kinda bummed out it was a flop.

Comment: @imerchant - perhaps it's your fault. Maybe if they'd called it "Richard from the UK" it would have stood a better chance. .. :-)